# Running Xcode 10 I get Codesigning error when building for my iPhone

Tags: ios, code-signing

So I am a Primary Teacher with no coding experience but I would like to develop a simple app to help teach phonics in my class.

However, I  have been trying to get builds to run on my device (iPhone 6s plus iOS 12.2). The simple app I made up said build succeeded on simulator but not the device. :< I can't fix that :<

```
Copy Swift standard libraries into /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app

Showing All Messages
CopySwiftLibs /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app (in target: GonativeIO)
    cd /Users/macbook/Desktop/ios\ 2
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 83FA19DF98CE2F83DBD4CABB58C1ADEE9F9E52CA --scan-executable /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/GonativeIO --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/PlugIns --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/ios\ 2/FBSDKShareKit.framework --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/ios\ 2/Bolts.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/ios\ 2/FBSDKLoginKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/ios\ 2/FBSDKCoreKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework --scan-folder /Users/macbook/Desktop/ios\ 2/OneSignal.framework --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GoNativeIOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: unstable(7)
libswiftos.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 83FA19DF98CE2F83DBD4CABB58C1ADEE9F9E52CA --verbose /Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/Users/macbook/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GonativeIO.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Codesigning+Failed+with+exit+code+1). This has been covered many, many times.

Answer (score 0):

running on simulator doesn't require code signing so you were able to run your app on that. Running on a device needs certificates. As suggested in the comment, kindly go through the steps enumerated in the following link:
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7